# AWS Api Gateway websocket to custom wensocket server in ecs behind ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-api-gateway, aws-application-load-balancer

I want to integrate websocket api to my ecs managed websocket api running behind ALB. Only http connections are allowd, so i am getting 426 error as upgrade required. How can i send websocket request from api gateway to ALB?

Comment: It is not possible. check [noninertialframe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70679996/aws-api-gateway-websocket-api-how-to-use-it-with-react-nodejs-native-websoc)